# Error in Script output in mkdir

Tags: linux, redhat

a=`date +"%F"`
b=`echo $a | cut -d'-' -f1`
c=`echo $a | cut -d'-' -f2`
d=`echo $a | cut -d'-' -f3`
mkdir -p /backup/$b_$c_$d

the output is "29". I expected /backup/2015_07_29

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using :

```
[root@mybox]# date +%Y_%m_%d
2015_07_29
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your example is this line:

```
mkdir -p /backup/$b_$c_$d
```

This looks for three variables: `b_`, `c_`, and `d`. I.e., the underscores are parsed as part of the identifier, and only your `d` is valid. If you want to proceed with the way you’re writing this, you’d need to separate your vars, like:

```
${b}_${c}_${d}
```

However, there are better ways to write your script, as a one-liner, such as the other solution proposed, or (for variety):

```
mkdir -p $(date -I |sed 's/-/_/g')
```

Keeping your dates in an ISO format might be preferred, so you could omit the sed-pipe.